# Can't get GPIOH pins to work as output on STM32F4 Discovery

Tags: gpio, output, stm32f4-discovery

I'm using 4 LEDs connected to different pins on STM32F4 Discovery: PA6, PD8, PH0, PD1. All of these pins have been configured as output with same function:

```
void initPins(uint32_t ahb_gpio, GPIO_TypeDef * gpio, uint16_t gpio_pin)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitDef;
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(ahb_gpio, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Pin = gpio_pin;
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitDef.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    //Initialize pins
    GPIO_Init(gpio, &GPIO_InitDef);
}

...

initPins(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_6);
initPins(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_8);
initPins(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOH, GPIOH, GPIO_Pin_0);
initPins(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_1);
```

The three pins on GPIOA and GPIOD work as they should, but I can't get pin on GPIOH to work. I tried also connecting 5th LED to PH1 and configuring it as output but it's no use, it won't work either. I also tried using TM GPIO library to configure pins:

```
TM_GPIO_Init(
    GPIOH,
    GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1,
    TM_GPIO_Mode_OUT,
    TM_GPIO_OType_PP,
    TM_GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL,
    TM_GPIO_Speed_High
    );
```

but it won't work either. I see these two pins can be used also for oscillator. Is that interfering with their configuration? Does anybody know why these pins are not working?

Comment: Are they open drain outputs?

Comment: @Andyaka You mean if they only support open drain? Because I configured them as PushPull.

Comment: I would suggest to generate start-up code with STM32CubeMX and compare your clock configuration code with generated one. Remember to set PH0 and PH1 as output in CubeMX

Comment: @Flanker I seem to not be able to use anything but HAL drivers with STMCubeMX.

Comment: Yes, but HAL is just a wrapper over CMSIS like SPL, you can follow the functions and structures to locate the difference

Comment: @Flanker Well I used STMCubeMX to set PH0 pin as output, it generated the initialization code and opened my IDE. I then tried turning on the PH0 and nothing happened.

Comment: It seems that if you use HSE those two pins cannot be used as GPIO. I thought that HSE is external crystal that I must add if I want to use it. Turns out it is already on board if I understand correctly the manual.